# Why is my AO a single colour ? ....grey

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking, baking

I want to bake **Ambient Occlusion** Map of my mesh, In **Blender Internal**, but once it is Baked it is a Single colour. I have no idea why.

[image]

I would like to know on what really the Ambient Occlusion Map depend on, should I adjust my lighting?

EDIT: World Settings

[image]

SECOND EDIT: My Materials are just default as when you press the **New** button.

[image]

*p.s. My first time baking AO*

**I actualy found out now that the Selection to Active was Checked, when I unckecked it everything worked fine, thanks for help Carlo.**

Comment: Can you add a screenshot with material and world settings? or attach the blend file.

Comment: @user277143 Unfortunately,I get the same result

Comment: Can you post your baking settings? Are you trying to bake High to Low poly? Is the option "Selected to active" active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to Bake the Selected Object pass to the Active object without selecting at least another object, the operation fails: no information can be baked.

[image]

To bake a texure from a single object, you should disable the option by unchecking the box.

[image]

It comes out  grey because in BI the ambient occlusion get coloured by the Diffuse color (grey in your case).

[image]